# Perl remove multiple line that match regex

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file that looks like this:

```
*
TEST CASE1,
$ some text unque633
PLACEMENT 123
*
TEST CASE2,
$ some text unque759
PLACEMENT 321
*
TEST CASE3,
$ some text unque966
PLACEMENT 856
*
```

I want to remove multiple lines that match regex. For example, need to remove starting from `TEST CASE2` until the line begining with `*`. How can this be done within perl script. 
Also, how would I edit text from `TEST CASE2` if I only know `unque759`.
Much appreciated.

Comment: Desired result can be achieved with perl one liner `perl -pe "s/TEST CASE2[^*]*//s" file_name` if provided data is stored in a file. Extra option `-i` can be utilized to make replacement in place, option `-i.bak` can be utilized to make backup of original file with extension **.bak**.

Comment: Correction `perl -0777 -pe "s/TEST CASE2[^*]*//s" file_name` (for Unix/Linux replace `"` with `'`).

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desired goal can be easily achieved with following algorithm: read all data into a variable, substitute block 'TEST CASE2.....' before next '*' to nothing, output result

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };     # read all data at once

$data =~ s/TEST CASE2[^*]*//s;          # substitute requested block with nothing

say $data;

__DATA__
*
TEST CASE1,
$ some text
PLACEMENT 123
*
TEST CASE2,
$ some text
PLACEMENT 321
*
TEST CASE3,
$ some text
PLACEMENT 856
*
```

Output

```
*
TEST CASE1,
$ some text
PLACEMENT 123
*
*
TEST CASE3,
$ some text
PLACEMENT 856
*
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked well. Also, how would I edit text from `TEST CASE2` to `TEST CASE25` if I only know `unque759`.

Comment: @Oleg Bukhantsov -- what is your definition **edit text from .... to ....**? You just want **to remove** 'TEST CASE2 ..... TEST CASE25' (Is 'TEST CASE25' inclusive or exclusive?) . Or you want really **edit** with modification of each block?

Answer (score 1):

This will remove blocks beginning with `TEST CASE2,`, ending with `*` and containing `unque759`

```
cat file.txt 
*
TEST CASE1,
$ some text unque633
PLACEMENT 123
*
TEST CASE2,
$ some text unque759
PLACEMENT 321
*
TEST CASE2,
$ some text unque999
PLACEMENT 321
*
TEST CASE3,
$ some text unque966
PLACEMENT 856
*

perl -0777 -ape 's/TEST CASE2,[^*]+?\bunque759\b[^*]+?\*(?:\R|\z)//' file.txt 
*
TEST CASE1,
$ some text unque633
PLACEMENT 123
*
TEST CASE2,
$ some text unque999
PLACEMENT 321
*
TEST CASE3,
$ some text unque966
PLACEMENT 856
*
```

**Explanation:**

```
-0777            # “slurp” mode, read the file in a single string
s/               # substitute
    TEST CASE2,     # literally
    [^*]+?          # 1 or more non asterisk, not greedy
    \b              # word boundary
    unque759        # literally
    \b              # word boundary
    [^*]+?          # 1 or more non asterisk, not greedy
    \*              # an asterisk
    (?:\R|\z)       # non capture group, end of line OR end of string
//               with nothing
```